# Twin y axes plot with monthly average as x-axis over multiple years with xarray

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-xarray, timeserieschart

Thank you for taking interest in this post.

I am hoping to create a twin y axes plot illustrating 2 variables (eg. y1=snowmelt and y2=discharge run-off). Due to my very limited knowledge in python as I have just started to learn coding, I am very confused as to how I can go about it.

I am able to construct a twin y axes plot and a plot representing monthly average of multiple years. However, I am not sure how to combine these matplotlib codes together and create a twin y axes plot with monthly average as x-axis over multiple years.

Code for monthly average

```
disda = xr.open_mfdataset(sorted(['1980.nc','1981.nc', '1982.nc', '1983.nc','1984.nc','1985.nc','1986.nc','1987.nc', '1988.nc','1989.nc', '1990.nc', '1991.nc', '1992.nc', '1993.nc', '1994.nc', '1996.nc', '1997.nc', '1998.nc','1999.nc']))
snowdepth_we = xr.open_dataarray('Snow depth water equivalent.nc')


disyrs = disda.sel(time=slice('1981','1999'))
snyrs = snowdepth_we.sel(time=slice('1981','1999'))


dismonthlymean = disyrs.dis24

dislatlonmean = dismonthlymean.mean(dim=['latitude','longitude']).resample(time='M').sum()
snowlatlonmean = snmonthlymean.mean(dim=['latitude','longitude'])


disgroupby = dislatlonmean.groupby("time.month").mean("time")
sngroupby = snowlatlonmean.groupby("time.month").mean("time")

#graph commands
myfig, myax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))

    
TYs = np.unique(dislatlonmean["time.year"])
disgroupby.plot.line('b-', color='blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=4, label='Discharge Mean')
for YY in TYs: 
    plt.plot(np.arange(1,13), dislatlonmean.sel(time=YY.astype("str")), 'b-', color='blue', alpha=0.2)        

TYs = np.unique(dislatlonmean["time.year"])
sngroupby.plot.line('b-', color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=4, label='Snowdepth Mean')
for YY in TYs: 
    plt.plot(np.arange(1,13), dislatlonmean.sel(time=YY.astype("str")), 'b-', color='blue', alpha=0.2)        
        

    
myax.set_title('Western Himalayas Snow Depth and River Indus Discharge Run-off 1981-1999')
myax.set_ylabel('m of water equivalent')
myax.set_xlabel('Month')
myax.set_xticks(range(1, 13))
myax.set_xticklabels(['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'])
myax.grid()
myax.legend(['Discharge Mean','Snowdepth'])
```

since this is not a twin y-axes plot, i was unable to plot 2 variables with different measurements together where one variable became a flat line in the graph, underneath the other graph
[image: monthly graph]

on the other hand, i was able to create a twin y-axes plot using these commands

```
disda_dis248199 = disda_dis24.loc['1981':'1999'].mean(dim=['latitude','longitude']).resample(time='M').mean()
snow8199 = snowdepth_we.loc['1981':'1999'].mean(dim=['latitude','longitude']).resample(time='M').mean()

x = disda_dis248199.time
y1 = snow8199
y2 = disda_dis248199

#plotting commands
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,8))

ax1.set_xlabel('Year')
ax1.set_ylabel('Snow depth water equivalent (m of w.e)')
ax1.plot(x, y1, color='red', label='River Discharge')
ax1.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='red')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis

ax2.set_ylabel('River Discharge (m3s−1)')  # we already handled the x-label with ax1
ax2.plot(x, y2, color='blue',alpha=0.4, label='Snow depth water equivalent')
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='blue')

fig.legend(loc="upper right")
ax1.set_title('Western Himalayas Snow Depth and River Indus Tributaries Comparison 1981 - 2016')
ax2.grid()
```

[image: twin y-axes plot]

I have tried to merge these 2 commands together, but to no avail.

As a result, I am wondering if there's any way I can plot a twin y-axes plot like the 2nd graph but with months as the x-axis and both lines on the graph will be representing 2 different variables.

In addition, as you can see in graph 1, somehow the legend only shows the discharge mean (bold lines) and actual yearly averages from 1981-1999 (thin lines), therefore, I am wondering how would I be able to fix this?

I greatly appreciate your help!! Please let me know if you require any more information, I will respond as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only gave part of your code, I cannot run it and thus also cannot change it for you. However, I will try to give an explanation on what should be changed in the first piece of code.

As a first step, you want to define a second `Axes` object similarly to how you did it in the second piece of code:

```py
myax2 = myax.twinx()
```

Since you now have two `Axes` instances, you'll need to specify on which `Axes` instance (either `myax` or `myax2`) you want to plot the data. This means that instead of

```py
disgroupby.plot.line('b-', color='blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=4, label='Discharge Mean')
sngroupby.plot.line('b-', color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=4, label='Snowdepth Mean')
```

you should do something such as

```py
disgroupby.plot.line('b-', ax=myax, color='blue', linestyle='-', linewidth=4, label='Discharge Mean')
sngroupby.plot.line('b-', ax=myax2, color='red', linestyle='-', linewidth=4, label='Snowdepth Mean')
```

Note the addition of `ax=...` in the list of (keyword) arguments. See [this part of xarray's documentation](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/user-guide/plotting.html#adding-to-existing-axis) for an example. In addition, you no longer want to use `plt.plot`, as this does not specify on which `Axes` instance to plot the data. Instead, you want to call the `plot` method of the `Axes` instance on which you want to plot the data. As an example, the first occurence of

```py
plt.plot(np.arange(1,13), dislatlonmean.sel(time=YY.astype("str")), 'b-', color='blue', alpha=0.2)
```

should be changed to

```py
myax.plot(np.arange(1,13), dislatlonmean.sel(time=YY.astype("str")), 'b-', color='blue', alpha=0.2)
```

and the second occurence should be changed to

```py
myax2.plot(np.arange(1,13), dislatlonmean.sel(time=YY.astype("str")), 'b-', color='blue', alpha=0.2)
```

Setting labels, titles, etc. is similar to how you did it in the second piece of code.

Small note about your `plt.plot` statements, you have `..., 'b-', color='blue', ...` in the list of arguments. While this works, you specify the color twice. You could either remove the `color='blue'` part or change `'b-'` to `'-'`.

Comment: It worked fantastic! Thank you so so much for your help! I really appreciate it!